# java commandline including .jar

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I am able to use:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java>javac -classpath mail.jar myFile.java
```

to compile,but when I try to run it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java>java -cp mail.jar myFile
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myFile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myFile
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: myFile.  Program will exit.
```

I tried using various combinations using "." and "-classpath" to denote class path as other posts have sugested but couldn't figure it out. I've compiled and successfully run a basic helloworld.java in the same folder. running as admin. using java runtime 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your current directory into the classpath as well:

```
java -cp .;mail.jar myFile
```

If that doesn't work, post `myFile.java` so we can see what might be going on.  For example, is `myFile` in the default package or is there a `package` statement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of the following:

- pack the jar first (use the `jar` command) and use `java -jar`
- not specify a classpath and just run your class file (standalone applications)
- (if the jarfile is a library) you need to include the current directory in your classpath

Comment: He has to specify a classpath because (apparently) his app depends on `mail.jar`.

Comment: Ah. Well, to be honest, I'm used to sticking my own files in the other jarfile (minecraft) :P

Comment: eventually i'm going to use "exej" to make it a .exe. its for an expired account notifier